# Trouble with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok, so I create a project.
Now I create two c++ classes in that project A and B.
A has some compilation errors. B is just fine and compiles fine.
Now, when I run B, it wouldn't run because A still has compilation errors.

So, I don't like to create a whole new project just because I want to create a new c++ file (scratch to experiment on) and toggle between the two projects.

Is there any way I can just have two c++ files existing independently in a single project?

In the current scenario, how do i build/compile and run only one of the c++ file (A or B) without the other one getting compiled and run as well.

This is why I never made the transition from sublime to VS.

Comment: You *could* create separate "A" and "B" build configurations and set the "Excluded from Build" flag on the two files to opposite states in each configuration, but this really isn't how projects are meant to be used.

Comment: You shouldn't. A project gets compiled into a dll, lib, or exe. You cannot build and link only part of the project.

Comment: What does it mean to "run B"? Isn't B a class?

Comment: Stick to "Sublime", whatever that is. It seems to promote all the wrong kinds of practices that you love. Visual Studio actually compiles and links your source files before running them, so compilation errors stop the process in its tracks.

Comment: Well, my lab requires me to only use VS. Please tell me the step by step process as I'm new to VS. It will be really appreciated.

Comment: Sublime Text has the same issue, really. If you have files in a project, you expect all of them to be part of the build process, but can configure it, just like in VS. Yes, it's possible to not use a project, which works great for things that aren't projects, but not so well for projects.

Comment: B is the source file and not the class.

Comment: A more typical way of achieving what I think you're trying to do would be to create separate A and B projects (solutions) and load each into a separate instance of VS at the same time.

Comment: @chris: In Sublime, I can just create a new file, name the extension to .cpp and run it independently.

Comment: @dlf: Yes, that serves the purpose but I don't want to create the whole project just to experiment on a scratch class.

Comment: @GuptillGunther, That would fall under my "not a project" classification. I think it's unfortunate that more IDEs don't let you work on individual non-project files, but the way to fix that in VS is to make the two separate files into two separate projects. It's definitely arguable that an IDE is way overkill for a non-project, though.

Comment: @GuptillGunther: Generally speaking, in VS, project=target. You seem to want a new target, so make a new project. Making a project seems to be some huge laborious task in your mind. It's not. Maybe if you stopped using the phrase "whole new project", and instead just called it a new project, you wouldn't have a problem. You can easily create two projects in one solution, and very easily switch between them.

Comment: FWIW, unless you're testing things that are not portable, you can use something like an online compiler. Surely the lab only requires VS for things you're actually using, not for tests.

Answer (score 2):

First Question: In Visual Studio, in your Solution Explorer, right click under your project and select "Add>New Item" and then select your code file format in the Window that pops up(C++ in your case). Enter a name for the file and then click the "Add" button.

Second Question:  In the solution explorer window, right click the file that you do not wish to be included in the project and select "Exclude from Project".  That file will not be compiled, but will still be visible in Visual Studio. When you want to include the file, same procedure: Right click the file, select "Include in project".

Comment: Thanks man, this was most helpful.

Comment: No problem! Visual Studio can be an animal.